# Should I include jQuery into the minified code with requireJS or browserify?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, requirejs, browserify

For module manangement tools such as `requirejs` or `browserify`, `jquery` should be loaded using `require` function. Moreover, `requirejs` or `browserify` provides bundle and minification, which can convert all dependent modules into one minified js file.

It looks quite simple. However, converting everything into one big file will **lose the advantage of CDN**. Previously, browser can make use of the cache of public sites which hosts jQuery CDN, but it will not work for the `bundle and minification` approach..

Is it good practice to include all third-party library into the minified code? If not, what is a better way?

Comment: you can use cdn version of third party libs and still use minification, at least in `requirejs` it is possible.

Comment: I've seen solid arguments going both ways. What will determine which way is the best really depends on your project.

Comment: Its all about browser caching and reducing the number of file requests. In theory you will get better caching from CDN files as they may already have been loaded from other websites, but I would tend to reserve that for really common files from a really reliable CDN. For security & reliability we bundle everything on our own servers, but the rules change per business. As Louis says it "really depends on your project".